# why there is no printout when using #[derive(Debug)] for rust in jupyter notebook?

Tags: rust, jupyter-notebook

I am new in rusting studying. when i am trying to execute some codes written by Rust in jupyter-notebook. I can not get any print out. but it can be executed via vscode or terminal.
[no print out in jupyter-notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO61Y.png)

Here is my code:

```
// Derive the `fmt::Debug` implementation for `Structure`. `Structure`
// is a structure which contains a single `i32`.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Structure(i32);

// Put a `Structure` inside of the structure `Deep`. Make it printable
// also.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Deep(Structure);

fn main() {
    // Printing with `{:?}` is similar to with `{}`.
    println!("{:?} months in a year.", 12);
    println!("{1:?} {0:?} is the {actor:?} name.",
             "Slater",
             "Christian",
             actor="actor's");

    // `Structure` is printable!
    println!("Now {:?} will print!", Structure(3));
    
    // The problem with `derive` is there is no control over how
    // the results look. What if I want this to just show a `7`?
    println!("Now {:?} will print!", Deep(Structure(7)));
}
```

snapshot for successful running in vscode
[successful print out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTFWn.png)

So, What's wrong? Are there any bugs for evcxr?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your environment/setup? What kernel version are you using? How did you setup your environment? From your question as-is, it is not possible to discern the root cause of your issue. Your question/issue is not invalid, it's just missing important helpful details. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips.

Comment: Does it work without `#[derive(Debug)]`, i.e. plain `println!()`s?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I tried to move the code from function main() out. and it works now. I am afraid that jupyter-notebook rust environment is not supporting put fn main() into it. But i can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: @PossiblyAShrub, my rust version is 1.57.0.  and installed exvcr for using rust in jupyter-notebook. the question I asked is I can't get the print outs when I use the mentioned codes. But now I found maybe I shouldn't use fn main() in jupyter-notebook. after I move the codes within main() out. I can get the print-out correctly in jupyter-notebook.

Comment: Good to hear! I posted an answer with this fix (for future viewers). I also found the reasoning as to why it works and linked + explained in by answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the usage of `fn main`. See https://github.com/google/evcxr/issues/183.

In a EVCXR notebook, `main` is not a special function. Thus, writing the following simply creates a function called `main`:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

To have the code within `main` actually run, one would need to call `main` explicitly:

```rust
main()
// => Hello, world!
```

Generally, in a jupyter notebook a main function is not even used at all. This is of course different from a normal rust executable which requires a main function.

---

Credits to finding the issue's root cause goes to @Jun Lv. I have simply added some reasoning as to why the fix works/problem occurs.